# React noob having issues exporting component to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

new to React and trying to pass a component from one js file to another but keep getting this error

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#'

I have index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as AnswerBox from './components/AnswerBox.js';


ReactDOM.render(
    <AnswerBox />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

then I have AnswerBox.js in the components folder

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import * as GetAnswerButton from './subcomponents/GetAnswerButton.js';

class AnswerBox extends React.Component{

    render(){
       return(
            <div>
                <div className="answerBox"></div>
                <GetAnswerButton />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
module.exports = AnswerBox;
```

then in a sub folder of components called subcomponents I have another files called GetAnswerButton.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class GetAnswerButton extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button>Click Me</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = GetAnswerButton;
```

I have index.html at the same level as index.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Landing Page</title>
 </head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

</body>
```

and index.css also at the same folder level as index.js

```
.answerBox {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:30px;
    width:75px;
}
```

It all works if I have all the js code in index.js but as soon as I split it into component js files I get this error.

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#'

I know its probably something obvious.
cheers

Comment: In your case: `export default class AnswerBox extends React.Component` and get rid of `module.exports`

Comment: When I change it to that I get this error instead Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Comment: Kenneth did a better job, his answer is more detailed than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix **import** and **module.exports**

You should use **export default** instead of `module.exports`

Update

```
module.exports = GetAnswerButton;
```

to

```
export default GetAnswerButton;
```

The way that you're importing is also incorrect. After you update to use **export default** update these **import** from

```
import * as GetAnswerButton from './subcomponents/GetAnswerButton.js';
```

to

```
import GetAnswerButton from './subcomponents/GetAnswerButton.js';
```

Comment: When I change it to that I get this error instead    Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: Make sure your import statement is is updated to. Where it should be 
import GetAnswerButton from './subcomponents/GetAnswerButton.js';

Comment: Brilliant thanks, that was a overspill from another error previous to this.

Answer (score 1):

Box

```
React from 'react';

import GetAnswerButton from './subcomponents/GetAnswerButton';

export default class AnswerBox extends React.Component{

    render(){
       return(
            <div>
                <div className="answerBox"></div>
                <GetAnswerButton />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Button

```
import React from 'react';

export default class GetAnswerButton extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button>Click Me</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

this should work.

if you dont want to export the class in declaration

try to export with

```
export default AnswerBox;
```